# How to pass array as variable in SQLCMD

Tags: sql-server, powershell, sqlcmd

I am trying to pass server names in sql script , but its not working.
Please help

SQL Script `patch_report.sql`, I am running via powershell giving error

```
SELECT * from table where server in ('$(trimsqlstr)')
```

Error

```
Msg 102,level Level 15, State 1, Server DBserver, Line 1
Incorrect syntax near 'server1'.
```

```bsh
$DB_server = 'DBserver'
$serverName = "server1
server2
server3
"
$serverName = $serverName -split "\n" | foreach {$_.ToString().TrimEnd()}
$trimsqlstr = foreach($server in $serverName){
if ($serverName.Indexof($server) -eq $($serverName.Length-1)){
"'$Server'"
} else {
"'$Server',"
}

SQLCMD.exe -v trimsqlstr = "$($trimsqlstr)" -E -S $DB_server -W -i patch_report.sql
```

I am expecting it to result like this

```sql
SELECT * from table where server in ('server1','server2','server3')
```

Comment: my code was not working because it had wrong syntax , I was wrapping  `('$(trimsqlstr)')` in `"'"` , I corrected it to `($trimsqlstr)` and it worked

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The accepted answer is an excellent solution, I just want to point you towards the `-join` operator.

The `-join` operator is very practical for joining members of an array to a string.

You can do something like this:

```
$serverNames = "server1
server2
server3
"

$serverNameArray = $serverNames -split "\n" | foreach {$_.ToString().TrimEnd()} | Where-Object {$_} | foreach {"'$_'"}
$whereClause = $serverNameArray -join ','
$selectQuery = "SELECT * from table where server in ($whereClause)"
```

`Where-Object {$_}` is removing the empty elements.

Comment: You could shorten further: `(($serverNames -split "\n").Trim() -ne ''| ForEach-Object{"'$_'"}) -join ','`

Answer (score 1):

You may use below code:

```
$DB_server = 'DBserver'
$serverName = "server1
server2
server3
"

$serverName = $serverName -split "\n" | foreach {$_.ToString().TrimEnd()}
ForEach($server in $serverName) 
{
$serverstring = $serverstring+"'"+$server+"'"+","
}
$trimsqlstr = $serverstring.Substring(0, $serverstring.Length-4)
```

And then use $trimsqlstr in query like below

```
SELECT * from table where server in ($trimsqlstr)
```